# python regex look around

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Could anyone figure out why these 2 results are totally different:

import re

```
a = re.findall(r'\w+(?=,|\.)',"They were three: Felix, Victor, and Carlos.") ; print(a)
a = re.findall(r'\w+(?=(,|\.))',"They were three: Felix, Victor, and Carlos.") ; print(a)
```

1st return : ['Felix', 'Victor', 'Carlos']

2nd return: [',', ',', '.']

Thanks,
Ascanio

Comment: `re.findall` - that is why. It returns the captured texts if you specify capturing groups. Capturing works even inside a look-around. Use `r'\w+(?=(?:,|\.))'` to obtain the same results in both cases.

Comment: And the link to the description: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: Thanks stribizhev! This is really helpful!

Comment: @stribizhev: could you please look into another question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580468/python-regex-look-ahead-positive-negative