# python regex look ahead positive + negative

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

This regex will get 456. My question is why it CANNOT be 234 from 1-234-56 ? Does 56 qualify  the (?!\d)) pattern since it is NOT a single digit. Where is the beginning point that (?!\d)) will look for?

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))')
a = pattern.findall("The number is: 123456") ; print(a)
```

It is in the first stage to add the comma separator like 123,456.

```
a = pattern.findall("The number is: 123456") ; print(a)
results = pattern.finditer('123456')
  for result in results:
    print ( result.start(), result.end(), result)
```

Comment: It'd help if you tell what you're expecting the regex to do

Comment: How did you get `123-456` ?

Comment: `?!` is negative look ahead token so `?!\d` will look ahead if there is no single  digit

Comment: Thanks SIslam. I am just curious why the whole number can't be parsed like 1-234-56 since ?!\d only exclude the SINGLE digit, 56 is not a single digit.

Comment: In think in your regex there is error since when i run`import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))')
a = pattern.findall("The number is: 123456")
print(a)` i get `['456']`

Comment: Yes, ['456'] is correct. please skip my original question. Why it is not ['234']  through 1-234-56?

Comment: I think you need to have look on regex! SO is for asking pointed problem not for broad discussion on a subject. better ask what you want from what  . I can post the what the regex '\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' is doing.

Comment: Do you need  [this](http://ideone.com/Q57jig)? The regex will look for any digit that is followed by 3-digit groups before a non-digit.

Comment: What do you really want to do?  If you just want to insert commas into a number string Python has an easier way: `format(int('1234567'),',')` -> `'1,234,567'`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for the offering. I just want to know how regex works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why it CANNOT be `234` from `1-234-56`?

It is not possible as `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` requires 3-digit sequences appear after a 1-3-digit sequence. `56` (the last digit group in your imagined scenario) is a 2-digit group. Since a quantifier can be either lazy or greedy, you cannot match both one, two and three digit groups with `\d{1,3}`. To get `234` from `123456`, you'd need a specifically tailored regex for it: [`\B\d{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/lD2yA3/2), or [`(?<=1)\d{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/lD2yA3/3) or even [`\d{3}(?=\d{2}(?!\d))`](https://regex101.com/r/lD2yA3/4).

> Does `56` match the `(?!\d))` pattern? Where is the beginning point that (?!\d)) will look for?

No, this is a negative lookahead, it does not match, it only checks if there is no digit right after the current position in the input string. If there is a digit, the match is failed (not result found and returned).

More clarification on the look-ahead: it is located after `(\d{3})+` subpattern, thus the regex engine starts searching for a digit right after the last 3-digit group, and fails a match if the digit is found (as it is a negative lookahead). In plain words, **the `(?!\d)` is a number closing/trailing boundary** in this regex.

A more detailed breakdown:

- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digit sequence, as many as possible (greedy quantifier is used)
- `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` - a positive look-ahead (`(?=...)`) that checks if the 1-3 digit sequence matched before are followed by

  - `(\d{3})+` - 1 or more (`+`) sequences of exactly 3 digits...
  - `(?!\d)` - not followed by a digit.

Lookaheads do not match, do not consume characters, but you still can *capture* inside them. When a lookahead is executed, the regex index is at the same character as before. **With your regex and input**, you match `123` with `\d{1,3}` as then you have 3-digit sequence (`456`). But `456` is *capured* within a lookahead, and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns only captured texts if capturing groups are set.

To just add comma as digit grouping symbol, use

```
rx = r'\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))'
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KdMCNi)

Comment: not by me. :-) I am sorry for the previous  inaccurate question. Have fixed  it.

Comment: @Ascanio: Does it answer your question? Or do you need more clarification of how `(?!\d)` works?

Comment: yes please! You read my mind! That is the root cause for the question.

Comment: @Ascanio:  I have added more clarifications, and updated the "main" question answer.

Comment: appreciate! (?!\d) - not followed by a digit. But 56 is 2 digits on the tail. So it should be fine?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding on your part. You have not read about `re.findall`. Lookaheads do not match, do not consume characters, but you still can *capture* inside them. When a lookahead is executed, the regex index is at the same character as before. You match `123` with `\d{1,3}` as then you have 3-digit sequence (`456`). But `456` is *capured* within a lookahead, and `re.findall` returns only captured texts if capturing groups are set.

Comment: I will regard the (?!\d) as a secured tail checker in future. Which means must match previous subpattern repeating N times , and nothing left then.